# Difference between calling a non-static method statically and not statically

Tags: php

Given the following code:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public function print() {
        echo $this->number . "\n";
    }

    public static function staticPrint() {
        echo "staticPrint\n";
    }
}

class MyExtendedClass extends MyClass {
    protected $number = 100;

    public function extendedPrint() {
        $this->print();
        $this::print(); // What's the difference?
        $this->staticPrint(); // Why is this allowed?
        $this::staticPrint();
        echo "Print done...!\n";
    }
}

$myExtendedClass = new MyExtendedClass();
$myExtendedClass->extendedPrint();
```

with the following output:

```
100
100
Print done...!
```

Is there any difference between `$this->print()`  and `$this::print()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361598/php-static-and-non-static-functions-and-objects

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9207510/398939?

Comment: Between `$this->print()` and `$this::print()` there is no difference. But between `$var->print()` and `$var::print()` there is (even inside class). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39891561/1421194).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, there is no any difference if you call it from **inside your class**.

**But**, if you call it from outside your class, you need instantiate first to call non-static method.

```
$var = new MyExtendedClass;
$var->print();
```

Static: (*deprecated on PHP 7*)

```
$var = MyExtendedClass::print();
```

on PHP 7, you need `Static` keyword on your method, so it can be call statically. [Full reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: `$var = MyExtendedClass::print();` you are calling a non-static method statically, in PHP 7.0 `$this` would be undefined.

Comment: @welcome : i acknowledged that, just updated my answer.

Comment: No, there is difference. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39891561/1421194).

Answer (score 1):

A method which is declared as `static` will always be called statically:

```
public static function bar() { var_dump($this); }
```

Whichever way you call this method, it will result in:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context
```

<sub>(Or variations thereof depending on your version of PHP.)</sub>

A function which does *not* have the `static` keyword behaves… differently:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar() { var_dump($this); }
}

$f = new Foo;
$f::bar();
```

```
Deprecated: Non-static method Foo::bar() should not be called statically
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Calling the function *from outside* actually calls it statically.

```
class Foo {
    public function bar() { var_dump($this); }
    public function baz() { $this::bar(); }
}

$f = new Foo;
$f->baz();
```

```
object(Foo)#1 (0) {
}
```

Calling the function via `$this::` calls it in an object context.

The manual only has [these vague paragraphs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) to offer for the `::` operator:

> When referencing these items from outside the class definition, use the name of the class.
>
> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).

It appears that outside a class `::` always operates statically, and `$f::` substitutes the name of the class. However, within an object context, `::` preserves the context, likely to enable correct operation of `parent::` calls, which obviously should preserve the object context.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave No, there is no difference.

Although there are totally different in most circumstances, since in the **non-static** you are printing the current number value of the **object**, which could have changed (any set method or similar could have been called).

Whereas with the **static** call it would print always the same value (default value declared in the **class** scope, 100).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:
**`$instance::method(…)`** (where `$instance` is a class instance, not a string) **seems to be equivalent to `get_class($instance)::method(…)`** (which in your case means `MyExtendedClass::print()`).

When you call `SomeClassName::method(…)`, the fact whether the `method` receives or not receives a `$this` value is sporadic. It depends on what place you call `SomeClassName::method(…)` from. Calling `SomeClassName::method(…)` from within same or other method of the `SomeClassName` or its descendant will cause *the `$this` from the place of calling* to be passed to `method`; otherwise `method` probably won't receive any `$this` value.

Thus, when you call `$instance::method(…)`, the `method` may or may not receive a `$this` value. If it receives a `$this` value, it will be **the `$this` value from the place of calling**, but **not the `$instance`** (although they may coincide, as when doing `$this::method(…)` or `$instance = $this; …; $instance::method(…)`).

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/93d4ea2dd47dbc2c5ed338a96ca4d00d4ffef77b